# Error in instantiating an object - Too many input arguments

Tags: matlab, oop, constructor, objectinstantiation

I created a class with the name Player. This is the code of the class

```
classdef Player

     properties
         Name
         Score
     end

     methods
     end

end
```

Now I use the following code to create an instance of the class. In the final line I attempt to print the value of properties

```
Player evergreen = new Player();
evergreen.Name = "Roger Federer" ;

evergreen
```

An error is thrown up while I run the script. This is the error - Error using Player
Too many input arguments.

> Error in Team (line 1) Player evergreen = new Player();

Team is the name of the file containing script.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have `new` keyword. Please read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/create-a-simple-class.html).

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative code

Comment: In the liked address it is explained how to define a class and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, it was reallly helpful

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Java, things in Matlab work a little bit differently. When working with classes, you don't need to specify the type when declaring variables and constructors must be called without the `new` keyword. While your code run perfectly under Java, in order to make it work under Matlab you have to rewrite it as follows:

```
p = Player();
p.Name = 'Roger Federer';
```

For a brief introduction to object oriented programming in Matlab, read [this](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/create-a-simple-class.html).